# Getting a list of user profiles on a computer in C++ Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the best way to enumerate all of the user profiles on a computer?

I know how to get the currently logged in user profile, and I know how to get the "all user" profile.  But I'd like to get a list of each and every profile on the computer.

Comment: Nit pick, but the "All users" profile doesn't really exist, it's just a container for some specific shared data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before going the undocumented route like flokra suggests, I would try [NetUserEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370652%28VS.85%29.aspx)() or [NetQueryDisplayInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370610%28VS.85%29.aspx)()

If you want to go into undocumented land, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` has a (incomplete) list of accounts (It's missing special accounts like ASPNET, HelpAssistant and SUPPORT_xxxx) It also has the path to the profile folder, which is a lot safer than using `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\..\` but why use it when there is [GetProfilesDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762278%28VS.85%29.aspx)()

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that (and actually search for this stuff in the msdn-library didn't bring this up). Now, it would be nice if your links to the documentation of these functions would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be very careful with that, in the presence of roaming profiles. When do you count a roaming profile to be on the computer? Also, do you have sufficient rights to access it? Even Local Admins don't have rights to network accounts, only network admins do IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

You could read in the contents of the directory one level above `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`.

Then you would have the names of all accounts that are (or were, if not deleted completely) on the system. To verify that an account still exists, I would use [LsaLookupNames2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721798(VS.85).aspx). This function retrieves the SIDs that belong to account-names (deleted account == no SID).

Comment: This will miss the SYSTEM profile, usually at `c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile`

Comment: In Windows 10, `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` is "C:\ProgramData", so going one directory above won't get you into "C:\users"