# How to get all windows user account name?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a list of user profiles on a computer in C++ Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376036/getting-a-list-of-user-profiles-on-a-computer-in-c-win32)

I should get all windows user accounts including "SYSTEM" and logged-in user's name.

But I don't know how to access it.

I'm using C++. So I want to know the Windows API to get the information.

Please help me.

Comment: Does it matter since most of win apis are available in C?