# How to get paths to user desktops from a service?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, desktop

I need to enumerate paths to desktop folders for all users on a local Windows system from a service application. The catch is that some users may not be logged in at the time. So is there any API, or some other method to do that?

**EDIT1:** For those who didn't read the first paragraph let me repeat -- **I do not have a token** to a user account, a user may not be logged in at the time.

**EDIT2:** I need this to remove a shortcut from user desktops before a feature supported by my application is turned off, or the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Could you assume most users are stored in the C:\Users\ path and only enumerate over the ones that are not defined by windows (Default,Public,etc)

Comment: @ConnorHollis, I don't think you can easily make that assumption - depending on the environment and OS version, the folder might have a different name, or could be on a network share, a different drive etc etc.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376036/getting-a-list-of-user-profiles-on-a-computer-in-c-win32 to get the list of all users. I couldn't find a way to get users' profile paths without logging them in, however.

Comment: @TimoGeusch Yeah I figured that was too simple

Comment: Thanks. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` looks pretty promising. But @TimoGeusch is correct, will it point correctly to all network and roaming desktops?

Comment: @HerrJoebob: If I get the profile path for a user account, am I safe to assume that the desktop path can be derived by adding "Desktop" to it?

Comment: No it could be any localized name, like %UserProfile%\桌面

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟: Thanks for your addition. I posted my solution below. Can I ask you to check it on your system?

Comment: Try SHGetFolderPath with a token obtained via the method in the documentation of GetUserProfileDirectory

Comment: Without a token, and without impersonation, it seems to me that reading, let alone deleting anything, from particular user profiles other than the current user will be problematic.

Comment: @JustinC: Yes, that's what I'm finding out. Although the data can be easily accessed in the file system folder, finding its path seems not to be as straightforward.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do what you're asking, because the user's desktop may be on a file server to which your program does not have access.  Why are you putting shortcuts on the user's personal desktops in the first place?  Why not use the All Users desktop?

Comment: Also, what if the user's desktop is shared between several machines, and the app/feature has been removed on some but not all of these machines?

Comment: @HarryJohnston how can a desktop be shared among several machines?

Comment: You can also configure a redirected desktop folder using group policy.  In our teaching labs, we use both redirected folders and roaming profiles, and the local copy of each profile is deleted when the user logs out.

Comment: Shared desktops (and documents, and application data, etc.) are essential when you're sharing a collection of computers with other people rather than having a particular computer that you always use.

Comment: OK, good points guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best method I was able to come up so far. So I'd appreciate if someone with a non-English installation of Windows could check this for me?

(I'm posting just a pseudo-code for brevity.)

1 - All of the steps below are done from a local service application.

2 - To get paths to all user profiles enumerate subfolders in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` key and read `ProfileImagePath` value from them. It will give profile paths for each user account.

3 - To get the folder name for the desktop, read the `Desktop` value from the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` key from the service app (yes, I know HKCU sounds strange, but it worked for me.) After that get the path for the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable, using [environment variable APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So you'll get two paths, something like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

and

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
```

Then simply isolate the 2nd string from the 1st, using case-insensitive comparison, and you'll get the folder name for the desktop, (i.e. "\Desktop" in this case.)

4 - Add the desktop folder to the path obtained in step 2 to produce the full path to that user's desktop folder.

Comment: problem of registry is it may not be created for a clean install and could change from machien to machine when the registry roams across machines http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟: I do appreciate Mr. Chen's input to the dying Win32 community, and he browses through this forum quite often himself, so maybe he'll put his two cents to my question. But honestly, most of his "Old New Things" pose more questions than answer them. We know that Windows doesn't do "now" what it was promised to do "yesterday", he's not saying anything new... You picked on `User Shell Folders` key for `Desktop`, so if we follow Chen's logic, it should've been opened at least once since Windows installation, right?

Comment: Can someone with OS other than English, confirm that `Desktop` value for the `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` key contains something other than `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"` or is not present?

Comment: This is not reliable.  You're assuming that all the users on the system have the same Desktop path relative to their profile folder, which is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

From userenv.h  :  GetProfilesDirectory (win2k+, iirc)

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762278(v=vs.85).aspx

Use this to find the directory containing all the local user account profile directories.

To find the desktop folder:

Shlobj.h  :  SHGetKnownFolderPath  (vista+)

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx

You'll need FOLDERID_Desktop as the known-folder id.  This symbol is declared in Knownfolders.h

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Using these, you might get closer to what you want without directly reading the registry.  Of course this belies any elegant way of enumerating the users aside  from inferring from the folder list within the 
GetProfilesDirectory.  Perhaps there is a more api appropriate way to enumerate the local users.

Secondly, and this depends on the purpose of your service, but perhaps by working with the  'allusers' profile, instead of each individually you won't need to know the current list of local users.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but again, all this stuff will work only if I have a user token, which I may not...

Comment: Not allowed, or not sure how?  If it is critical that this is the approach, there are some less documented means of obtaining a token, of which I am only vaguely familiar with (NtCreateToken I believe is one) otherwise, perhaps rethinking the problem and the approach will give you a good, alternative solution.