# How do I get the user name of the current user?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to access the user name in the Windows using C programming and use that name to create the path to the particular file like "c:\users\john\Roaming.....and so on". So for every system user name e.g "john" is different. Help me to find the user name at run time.

Comment: Do you need to get only the current user's name or [all user names in the system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376036/getting-a-list-of-user-profiles-on-a-computer-in-c-win32)?

Comment: `getenv("USERNAME")` should do it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 8):

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", getenv("USERPROFILE"));  // Print user's home directory.
    return 0;
}
```

To get the user name instead of the home path replace `USERPROFILE` with `USERNAME`.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for, here, is probably more [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx). The function lets you find per-user special folders. This is preferred to querying usernames because the home folder may not have the same name as the user.

```
WSTR* location;
HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &location);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // location contains the folder path
    // call CoTaskMemFree to free up the memory once you're done with it
    CoTaskMemFree(location);
}
```

The list of so-called known folders is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx).

Comment: This is most likely what the OP needs. To get the name of each individual user doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 2):

The function to get user name on windows is [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587426/get-current-username-in-c-on-windows/11587467#11587467), probably, will help you too.

Comment: All basic Win32 APIs are C and so is `GetUserName` why do you say it's `C++`? Did you try clicking on the link in the answer, it's not the one in your comment to the question.

Comment: The tab-like heading of the box containing the function declaration does say C++. I guess MSDN simply conflates C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the following code to get the Username.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void main(void)
    {
        //following gets the appdata folder
        char szAppData[1024];
        char * szBufer      = 0;
        szBufer = getenv ("APPDATA");
        if (szBufer != NULL)
        {
           strcpy(szBufer , szAppData);
        }

        //following code gets the user name
        char szOSUserName[1024];
        szBufer = getenv ("USERNAME");
        if (szBufer != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(szBufer , szOSUserName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the current user with [`GetUserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD cch = UNLEN + 1;
    if (GetUserName(name, &cch))
    {
        char cmd[100 + UNLEN + 1];
        sprintf(cmd, "echo The username is \"%s\"", name); // Silly demo command
        system(cmd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use [`GetUserNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435) if you want the name in a specific format.

If you need to get the path to a special folder like "My Documents" or "Desktop" you should use the special folder functions like [`SHGetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188).

Answer (score 1):

`%USERNAME%` will give you the username, but a better solution is to store it on `%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\key.txt` to at least make it OS-independent.

And an even better solution would be not to store private information on the users' desktops. Or anywhere.

Comment: I stored it on desktop just for testing, not going to really save it there :D

Comment: This question is tagged as C, only batch files should use environment variables.

Comment: The Desktop folder might not be located in the users profile root! I could also do "set USERNAME=Administrator" before starting the program...

Comment: @Anders, you can delete your own hard drive if you want, how is that in any way relevant to anything?

Comment: Why would you rely on fragile environment variables when there are documented functions you can use instead that always gives the correct result? Your "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" example will return the wrong path for some people, it should not be a part of any marked answer IMHO.  Another example then. Some build tools like SCONS will delete most environment variables and reset things like %PATH% so it has a clean and repeatable environment.

Comment: Noted, don't use SCONS.